# React testing library how to use waitFor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm following [a tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/8-simple-steps-to-start-testing-react-apps-using-react-testing-library-and-jest/) on React testing. The tutorial has a simple component like this, to show how to test asynchronous actions:

```
import React from 'react'

const TestAsync = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0)

  const delayCount = () => (
    setTimeout(() => {
      setCounter(counter + 1)
    }, 500)
  )
  
  return (
    <>
      <h1 data-testid="counter">{ counter }</h1>
      <button data-testid="button-up" onClick={delayCount}> Up</button>
      <button data-testid="button-down" onClick={() => setCounter(counter - 1)}>Down</button>
    </>
  )
}
  
export default TestAsync
```

And the test file is like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, cleanup, fireEvent, waitForElement } from '@testing-library/react';
import TestAsync from './TestAsync'

afterEach(cleanup);
  
it('increments counter after 0.5s', async () => {
  const { getByTestId, getByText } = render(<TestAsync />); 

  fireEvent.click(getByTestId('button-up'))

  const counter = await waitForElement(() => getByText('1')) 

  expect(counter).toHaveTextContent('1')
});
```

The terminal says `waitForElement` has been deprecated and to use `waitFor` instead.

How can I use `waitFor` in this test file?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you're [waiting for appearance](https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-disappearance/), you can use it like this:

```js
it('increments counter after 0.5s', async() => {
  const { getByTestId, getByText } = render(<TestAsync />);

  fireEvent.click(getByTestId('button-up'));
  
  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(getByText('1')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Checking `.toHaveTextContent('1')` is a bit "weird" when you use `getByText('1')` to grab that element, so I replaced it with `.toBeInTheDocument()`.

Comment: Would it be also possible to wrap the assertion using the `act` function? Based on the docs I don't understand in which case to use `act` and in which case to use `waitFor`.

Comment: @RobBauer act is used when you want to simulate user interaction, waitFor is intended for async operations and DOM changes

Answer (score 5):

Current best practice would be to use `findByText` in that case. This function is a wrapper around `act`, and will query for the specified element until some timeout is reached.

In your case, you can use it like this:

```
it('increments counter after 0.5s', async () => {
  const { findByTestId, findByText } = render(<TestAsync />); 

  fireEvent.click(await findByTestId('button-up'))

  const counter = await findByText('1')
});
```

You don't need to call `expect` on its value, if the element doesn't exist it will throw an exception

You can find more differences about the types of queries [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about)

Answer (score 3):

> Would it be also possible to wrap the assertion using the act
> function? Based on the docs I don't understand in which case to use
> act and in which case to use waitFor.

The answer is yes. You could write this instead using act():

```
    import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";

        it('increments counter after 0.5s', async() => {
          const { getByTestId, getByText } = render(<TestAsync />);

// you wanna use act() when there is a render to happen in 
// the DOM and some change will take place:
          act(() => {
              fireEvent.click(getByTestId('button-up'));
          });
            expect(getByText('1')).toBeInTheDocument();
        });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think this is wrong, fireEvent should already use `act` internally