# setState not working in Jest test using React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, setstate

On a given component, I'm mocking an API call which returns some markup for an HTML document. I managed to get the mock working and the mock response is being returned, but my component is not able to set the state with this response. Here's how it looks like.

```
export const RetrieveContent = (props: Props) => {
  const [content, setContent] = useState < Partial < ContentViewModel >> {};
  useEffect(() => {
    const requestContent = async (props: Props) => {
      const { id } = props;
      const data = await getContent(id);
      // console.log(data) <-- This logs the object correctly!
      setContent(data);
    };
    requestContent(props);
  }, []);
  return <>{parse(content.contentObject.content.body)}</>; // content is an empty object here
};
```

After calling `setState`, the state is still an empty object. The test is rather simple.

```
cconst server = setupServer(
  rest.get('/content/*', (req, res, ctx) => {
    return res(ctx.json(ContentViewModelMock))
  })
)

describe('<Content /> tests', () => {

  beforeAll(() => server.listen())
  beforeEach(() => server.resetHandlers())
  afterAll(() => server.close())

  test('should display content when the id is found', async () => {
    const { asFragment } = render(<Content id={`${faker.datatype.uuid}`} />)
    console.log(asFragment().textContent) // This returns nothing
  })
})
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65725591/react-testing-library-how-to-use-waitfor does this help you?

Comment: After a bit of digging, looks like I needed the async utilities provided by Testing Library, I also needed to upgrade my React scripts and jest versions to get them working